# Generating a mouse heatmap with X, Y coordinates

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I'm trying to use Python to generate a mouse heatmap using a large set of X, Y coordinates. I've imported the CSV using Pandas, here's the first few rows to get an idea of what it looks like:

```
      X    Y
0  2537  638
1  2516  637
2  2451  644
3  2317  652
4  2147  658
5  1999  647
```

I've tried using Matplotlib with not a lot of success, so swapped over to Seaborn to attempt to generate the heatmap that way. For reference, this is what I'm hoping to generate (with a different image in the background):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdvGT.jpg

This is what my current code looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Jen\Desktop\mp.csv')
df[["x", "y"]] = pd.DataFrame.to_numpy(df)

matrix = np.zeros((df.x.max()+1, df.y.max()+1))
matrix[df.x, df.y] = df.index
sns.heatmap(matrix, cmap='jet')
plt.show()
```

With the following as a result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UcGT.jpg

Obviously, this isn't exactly what I'm going for. First off, my x and y axes are swapped. What do I need to do to make my result look more like the example I provided? How do I create that blob effect around the different points?

More than happy to try anything at this point. This dataset is about 13,000 rows but I anticipate it will be even larger in the future.

(For reference, these were captured using 2 monitors, each at a resolution of 1650x1050, hence the large x values)

Comment: Maybe `sns.kdeplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', cmap='inferno')` works for you? Please [avoid `jet`](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/).

Comment: Hi Johan! This definitely looks better (the axes appear to be correct now). New result is here: https://i.imgur.com/VXy4siT.png

Besides the color palette, do you have any other recommendations for how to make it look more like the heatmap example I gave in the original post?

Comment: You might want to experiment with the `thresh=` (enlarge the part considered "empty") and `cut=3` to enlarge the area shown.